# using x.reshape on a 1D array in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to use sklearn to use a simple decision tree classifier, and it complained that using a 1D array is now depricated and must use X.reshape(1,-1). So I did but it has turned my labels list to a list of lists with only one element so number of labels and samples do not match now. Another words my list of labels=[0,0,1,1] turns into [[0 0 1 1]]. Thanks

This is the simple code that I used:

```
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np
features =[[140,1],[130,1],[150,0],[170,0]]
labels=[0,0,1,1]
labels = np.array(labels).reshape(1,-1)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features,labels)
print clf.predict([150,0])
```

Comment: I suspect you may have wanted this: `labels = np.asarray(labels)[:, None]`?

Comment: This seems to be the equivalent of using reshape(-1,1) instead of (1,-1). It gives the right answer but I still get the deprecation warning

Comment: presumably, once the use of 1D arrays is fully deprecated, the authors of sklearn will have to modify that (and presumably other) functions to take account of it. I've always understood an array of `shape` (x, y) to be 2D, even if `x or y == 1`. That said, I've been wrong before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reshaping the wrong thing. Reshape the data your are predicting on, not your labels.

```
>>> clf.predict(np.array([150,0]).reshape(1,-1))
array([1])
```

Your labels have to align with your training data (features) ,so the length of both arrays should be the same. If labels is reshaped, you are right, it is a list of lists with a length of 1 and not equal to the length of your features.

You have to reshape your test data because prediction needs an array that looks like your training data. i.e. each index needs to be a training example with the same number of features as in training. You'll see that the following two commands return a list of lists and just a list respectively.

```
>>> np.array([150,0]).reshape(1,-1)
array([[150,   0]])
>>> np.array([150,0])
array([150,   0])
```

Comment: You are right. No warnings and the right result. Some extra explanation would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.